# AngularJS - Enable and disable button

Tags: angularjs

I have a condition and it is only on selecting an image among the optional images the next button needs to get enabled and also next should not get enabled on last outer select.

The problem here is on selecting the first image, the button is getting enabled and the scope is assigning the value to false and it is not getting true for the second iteration of images. How can I fix this issue?

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-10 col-lg-7">
    <div ng-repeat="outer in outers track by $index">
        <div ng-if="outer_index== $index">
            <div ng-bind="::outer.label"></div>
            <ul class="list-group">
                 <li class="cursorPointer" ng-repeat="inner in outer.inners | orderBy: 'id'" ng-class="{'selected': getSelectedClass($parent.$index, $index)}" class="deselected">
                     <div class="col-xs-6">
                         <div class="img">
                         <img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{inner.base64Icon}}"  alt="{{inner.description}}" title="{{inner.description}}"
                             ng-click="process()">
                         <div class="desc" ng-bind="inner.description"></div></div>
                     </div>
                 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-disabled="outer_index == outers.length -1 || disableNext" ng-click="getNext()">Next</button></div>
```

**In JS code, to activate the button only if,**

```
$scope.disableNext=true;
    $scope.process = function() {
    $scope.disableNext=false;
}

$scope.getNext = function (){
    $scope.outer_index = $scope.outer_index + 1;
    $scope.datas = $scope.outers[$scope.outer_index];
}
```

NOTE: I tried
`ng-click="process();disableNext=false;"` for this condition won't work within `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure to understand, why it should be set to true, I didn't seen where you set it to true.

Comment: By default ,I am setting the disableNext to true which is used in ng-disabled=true to make the button disable on load and if any image is clicked it will call process and change the $scope.disableNext to false whereas the button will get enabled.

Comment: So when you select an image the button is enabled ? does it work ? If it is I don't understand your problem. Maybe you want disable it after getnext() ?

Comment: Yes , got your idea and it will work.Thanks Mathieu!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the disableNext to true after selecting next and it works!

```
$scope.getNext = function() {
    $scope.disableNext=true;
    $scope.outer_index = $scope.outer_index + 1;
    $scope.datas = $scope.outers[$scope.outer_index];
}
```